# SAM Resource Layer - Can it Reference Another Layer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-lambda-layers

Building an AWS SAM application.

I wrote a shared layer, and then noticed I happened to reference another layer (force of habit).

Probably not best practice, but to save myself some time... anyone know if I can reference that other layer in the `Serverless::LayerVersion` build?

Essentially a layer `within a layer` (we'll call this "inception layer" haha)?

**Here's my shared layer**

```
Resources:
  sharedLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      ContentUri: shared
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.8
```

**I tried:**

```
Resources:
  sharedLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      ContentUri: shared
      Layers:
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:990458801000:layer:PyMySql:1
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.8
```

But it didn't like that.

**Important Note:** I do NOT want to put the PyMySql layer in my Globals as I don't want it attached to every function in my SAM app.  Any layer I put in the Globals seems to get attached to every function in the SAM build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one quasi-hack I figured out is if the "shared layer" is dependent on another layer, if you load the `dependent layer` first in the same Serverless::Function you're calling "shared layer" then it will work.

**Example:**

```
Resources:
  sharedLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      ContentUri: shared
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.8
```

This shared layer depends on `- arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:990458801000:layer:PyMySql:1`

**So in your function if you call that layer first:**

```
surfModel:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: search/surf_model
      Layers:
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:990458801000:layer:PyMySql:1
        - !Ref sharedLayer
```

Then `!Ref sharedLayer` will operate just fine (drawing on the reference to the dependent layer within the function itself).

Not the ideal solution, but it'll do for a short term fix.